# Need help getting latest CentOS iso DVD image

Tags: linux, centos

I've been trying to get the latest version of CentOS, but every time I try, it fails somewhere.  It's a 4 GB file.

[The mirror list on CentOS.org](https://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/) has a bunch of sites, but none have worked.

It lists many FTP sites as well, but no instructions such as port and password to connect.  (using Filezilla)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: Thanks for the two answers below.  zsinx6, I stopped using torrents years ago.  0PT1MU5 PR1ME, that was one of the sites I also tried.  BUT!  I had one more download from their CentOS main download page going https://wiki.centos.org/Download and watched it to completion.  Right now, my theory is that it's a Schroedinger's Cat thing, and I had to actually observe it to get it to work!  Still, appreciate the answers and will leave this question up in case anybody knows about the FTP which strikes me as the right way to download a 4 GB file. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried torrent? 
In the following link, choose .torrent
http://mirror.nbtelecom.com.br/centos/7/isos/x86_64/